# Laravel - Homestead env shows "404 File Not Found"

Tags: laravel, homestead

I've set up Laravel local envroment using Homestead.
When I accessed to "http://homestead.app/", browser showed "404 File Not Found".

[Local - homestead.yaml]

```
ip: "192.168.15.10"
folders:
     - map: ~/Code
       to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
     - map: homestead.app
       to: /home/vagrant/Laravel/public
       hhvm: true
     - map: firstapp.local
       to: /home/vagrant/firstapp/public
       hhvm: true
```

[Homestead]

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ ls
Code  firstapp  Laravel
```

The directory I created is built by following composer command.

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel firstapp --prefer-dist
composer create-project laravel/laravel Laravel dev-develop
```

What's the problem? If possible, could you tell me how to create Laravel project.

Answer (score 0):

```
folders:
     - map: ~/Code
       to: /home/vagrant/Code
```

You map your code to `home/vagrant/Code`

But your `sites:` references a different folder

```
sites:
     - map: homestead.app
       to: /home/vagrant/Laravel/public
       hhvm: true
     - map: firstapp.local
       to: /home/vagrant/firstapp/public
       hhvm: true
```

Change `/home/vagrant/Laravel/public` and `/home/vagrant/firstapp/public` to
`/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public` and `/home/vagrant/Code/firstapp/public`